# while error thrown by artisan custom command, it is not getting caught in laravel exception handler

Tags: php, laravel, exception, laravel-jobs

When running custom artisan command which dispatches job, if any exception occur in job it should call handler.php but it doesn't get called.
I need to send an email for each type of exception caught in job.

Answer (score -1):

=====edited=====

I see. so you want the jobs to retry a certain number of times and if it fails you want to send an email with the specific reason.

In this case you should not catch the exceptions inside your job with try-catch blocks. instead create the failed-table using `php artisan queue:failed-table` and handle the exceptions inside the failed function which you can create in the job like:

```
public function failed(Throwable $exception)
{
    // Send user notification of failure, etc...
}
```

for further information see the laravel docs:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#dealing-with-failed-jobs

Comment: thanks for the responding i have try-catch block in job i'm catching all types of exceptions there only, I need to send an email once any type of exception reaches its threshold value.

Comment: I see the problem now. edited the answer

Comment: I have an static AlarmException class which keeps count of each type of exceptions and throws an email if reaches threshold value. i just want to make it centralized so i can use it wherever i want by just calling AlarmException in one place, currently i'm calling it in catch block which catches the exceptions thrown from different classes and sending type of exception as a param.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question, "why handler.php does not catch exceptions in console commands", maybe someone wants to call bugsnag or smth else